# Não consigo instalar nenhuma extensão nem usar o 'Settings Sync' no VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

## O que eu fiz:

- Instalei o Windows 11 Pro;
- Rodei o Script [Win Debloat Tools](https://github.com/LeDragoX/Win-Debloat-Tools) ;
- Instalei o WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) através do PowerShell;
- Instalei o [ArchWsl](https://github.com/yuk7/ArchWSL), funcionando corretamente;
- Instalei o VS Code através da Microsoft Store.

## Problema:

Não consigo instalar nenhuma extensão nem ativar o 'Settings Sync'.

## Output:

```
2023-02-09 20:21:37.389 [warning] Via 'product.json#extensionEnabledApiProposals' extension 'github.vscode-pull-request-github' wants API proposal 'commentsResolvedState' but that proposal DOES NOT EXIST. Likely, the proposal has been finalized (check 'vscode.d.ts') or was abandoned.
2023-02-09 20:21:37.711 [error] Error scanning installed extensions:
2023-02-09 20:21:37.712 [error] SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.factory (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/pedro/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:741:99212)
2023-02-09 20:21:38.343 [error] SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.factory (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/pedro/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:88:93520)
2023-02-09 20:21:38.378 [error] Unexpected end of JSON input: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.factory (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/pedro/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:88:93520)
2023-02-09 20:21:38.471 [error] SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.factory (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/pedro/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:88:93520)
2023-02-09 20:21:38.484 [error] SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.factory (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/pedro/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:88:93520)
2023-02-09 20:21:38.514 [error] SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.factory (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/pedro/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:88:93520)
2023-02-09 20:21:40.152 [error] Unexpected end of JSON input: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.factory (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/pedro/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:88:93520)
2023-02-09 20:21:40.430 [info] [perf] Render performance baseline is 32ms
2023-02-09 20:21:44.390 [error] SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.factory (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/pedro/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:88:93520)
2023-02-09 20:21:44.420 [error] SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.factory (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/pedro/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:88:93520)
2023-02-09 20:21:44.430 [error] SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.factory (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/pedro/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:88:93520)
2023-02-09 20:21:44.432 [error] SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.factory (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/pedro/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:88:93520)
```

## DevTools:

[DevTools Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qs9g.png)

#### Reinstalei o VS Code várias vezes, tanto através da Microsoft Store quanto do site oficial.

## Soluções que procurei:

- [Extension wants API proposal 'localization' but that proposal DOES NOT EXIST](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/164255) ;
- [Extensions are not loaded if there is an invalid extensions.json file in extensions folder](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/168497) .

Answer (score 0):

Tive um problema semelhante, parece q é um problema com a versão nova, tenta baixar uma mais antiga, eu baixei essa https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_69 e funcionou pra mim, para baixar é só clicar no User ali [inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CW8rT.png)